# Where do I need to put JDBC driver for MySQL in the Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

In a Java project (for example with Netbean, Eclipse, IntelliJ), I usually put the JDBC driver for MySQL in the libs folder of the project, and It worked fine. However, for the Android Studio project, the program cannot see the driver. I tried some methods: put jar library of JDBC in the libs, and add Dependency module, but both did not work for me. Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mytextview;
    Button mybutton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mytextview = findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
        mybutton = findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        mybutton.setOnClickListener(onclick);
    }

    View.OnClickListener onclick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            (new Task()).execute();
        }
    };

    class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        String records = "Success! Results are: ", error = "";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try{
                //Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql6.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/sql6397885", "sql6397885", "4LMhjvCUYs");
                Statement stm =con.createStatement();
                ResultSet res = stm.executeQuery("select * from tbl_products");
                while(res.next()){
                    records += res.getInt(1) + ", " + res.getString(2)+ ", " +res.getString(3)+", "+res.getString(4) + "\n";
                }
                con.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                error = "Error: " + e.getMessage() + ", " + e.toString();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            mytextview.setText(records);
            if(error != "")
                mytextview.setText(error);
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
}
```

The info for database still works. I just use a free hosting with DB for testing. It works fine. I used mysql jdbc driver 8.0.0.23 (the latest one).

Also, with the same above code in doInBackground function, I test with a normal Java project, I work fine. Just does not work with Android Studio Project because it cannot find the jar lib.

Comment: JDBC is not designed for mobile devices, for both reliability and security reasons. I strongly recommend that you do something else, such as have your app talk to a Web service that, in turn, talks to your MySQL database.

Comment: would you please try to explain what exactly you are trying to achieve here. the architecture that you are considering here is incorrect. you must interface your android app to a web API which in turn will connect to your DB

Comment: Don't use JDBC drivers in Android. Use a webservice to mediate between your application and the database. And if you really want to use JDBC anyway, you'll need to use an older 5.1.x driver, because MySQL Connector/J 8 uses Java features not available on Android and will therefor not work.